# Unused Parameters in UPDATE Statement: LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, linq, linq-to-sql

I have SQL statements generated like the following. Note that the parameters @p1 and @p2 are not at all used and no way needed. Why is it coming? How can we remove them?

Note: UpdateCheck is Never for all columns.

Note: The database is updated correctly.

ISSUE

```
UPDATE [dbo].[BankAccount]
SET [Status] = @p3
WHERE [BankAccountID] = @p0
-- @p0: Input Int (Size = -1; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [10000]
-- @p1: Input NChar (Size = 10; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [Fixed     ]
-- @p2: Input NChar (Size = 10; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [Savings   ]
-- @p3: Input NChar (Size = 10; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [FrozenFA]
```

Auto generated class

```
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.TableAttribute(Name="dbo.BankAccount")]
[InheritanceMapping(Code = "Fixed", Type = typeof(FixedBankAccount), IsDefault = true)]
[InheritanceMapping(Code = "Savings", Type = typeof(SavingsBankAccount))]
public partial class BankAccount : INotifyPropertyChanging, INotifyPropertyChanged
```

TABLE

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[BankAccount](
[BankAccountID] [int] NOT NULL,
[AccountType] [nchar](10) NOT NULL,
[OpenedDate] [datetime] NULL,
[Status] [nchar](10) NULL,
[AccountOwnerID] [int] NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_BankAccount] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[BankAccountID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

CODE

```
public class LijosSimpleBankRepository : ILijosBankRepository
{
    public System.Data.Linq.DataContext Context
    {
        get;
        set;
    }


    public List<DBML_Project.BankAccount> GetAllAccountsForUser(int userID)
    {
        IQueryable<DBML_Project.BankAccount> queryResultEntities = Context.GetTable<DBML_Project.BankAccount>().Where(p => p.AccountOwnerID == userID);
        return queryResultEntities.ToList();
    }

    public List<T> GetAllAccountsofType<T>() where T : DBML_Project.BankAccount
    {
        var query = from p in Context.GetTable<DBML_Project.BankAccount>().OfType<T>()
                    select p;

        List<T> typeList = query.ToList();
        return typeList;

    }

    public virtual void UpdateAccount(DBML_Project.BankAccount bankAcc)
    {
        //UPDATE statement will be called only if there has happened a change
        Context.SubmitChanges();
    }

}



namespace ApplicationService_Bank
{
public class BankAccountAppService
{
    public RepositoryLayer.ILijosBankRepository AccountRepository { get; set; }

    public void FreezeAllAccountsForUser(int userId)
    {
        IEnumerable<DBML_Project.BankAccount> accounts = AccountRepository.GetAllAccountsForUser(userId);
        foreach (DBML_Project.BankAccount acc in accounts)
        {

            string getTypeResult = Convert.ToString(acc.GetType());



            acc.Freeze();
            AccountRepository.UpdateAccount(acc);
        }

    }

}


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it is including the discriminator values as parameters? Presumably there are some cases where it *uses* those in an inheritance-related update (perhaps as part of concurrency checking, although it looks like you've disabled that), and it was simply *really hard and not worth it* to ignore them in the cases where it wasn't needed, or simply: a bug crept in. Either way, it doesn't do any harm, other than making the query a tiny tiny bit larger. Not enough to notice.